# How to stop Debugger in eclipse to scroll automaticly pages?

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I want debugger not scroll pages by him self even if current debugging statement will go out of visible area. I have some reasons for that.

Comment: Add **Some reasons**. There might be some other ways to achieve this

Comment: it is just annoying that code jumps all the way around, up and down. It is much nicer for me to scroll code by my self even while debugging.